# Data transfer between tab view controllers - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There are 3 child tab view controllers. There are labels as 0 in view controllers. If the number(0) of labels increases in any view controller, I want to increase from the others. How can i do this data transfer.

[image: Mobile views]

```
class tab1Controller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
     var count = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        count = countLabel.text!
        UserDefaults.standard.set(count, forKey: "count")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }

class tab2Controller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel2: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        countLabel2.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "count")

    }
```

I did something like this but it didn't work

Comment: you can have singleton class to have that variable ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the code you're actually using, we can't really tell what the issue is with "something like this". Also, be more specific than "it didn't work". Finally, as an aside: calling `synchronize()` has been soft-deprecated for ages now. Remove the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way in your case is to update the label text in viewWillAppear method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  countLabel.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "count")
}
```

You also should update the value in UserDefaults every time the number changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it i viewWillAppear() instead of viewDidLoad().. Because DidLoad() of all controllers called when tabBar construct and show first tab ...

```
@IBOutlet weak var countLabel2: UILabel!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  countLabel.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "count")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your child controllers are created at the same when the tab controller created. In such cases that needed to notify other existing controllers, you must use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter).

> A notification dispatch mechanism that enables the broadcast of information to registered observers.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didReceiveCountData = Notification.Name("didReceiveCountData")
}

class tab1Controller: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Listen notifications for name .didReceiveCountData.
        // onDidReceiveCountData(_:) will be called when notification received.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveCountData(_:)), name: .didReceiveCountData, object: nil)

     }

    // This will be called when the count changes.
     @objc func onDidReceiveCountData(_ notification:Notification) {
        if let newCount = notification.object as? String {
            countLabel.text = newCount
        }
     }

    // Call this when you need to change count and notify other tabs.
    private func changeCount(_ newCount: String) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveCountData, object: newCount)
    }
}

class tab2Controller: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Listen notifications for name .didReceiveCountData.
        // onDidReceiveCountData(_:) will be called when notification received.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveCountData(_:)), name: .didReceiveCountData, object: nil)

     }

    // This will be called when the count changes.
     @objc func onDidReceiveCountData(_ notification:Notification) {
        if let newCount = notification.object as? String {
            countLabel.text = newCount
        }
     }

    // Call this when you need to change count and notify other tabs.
    private func changeCount(_ newCount: String) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveCountData, object: newCount)
    }
}
```

Comment: can I contact you via linkedin?

Comment: ofc, here is my account https://www.linkedin.com/in/orcundeniz/